# How to use static code analyzer CPD ignoreLiterals and ignoreIdentifiers from command-line?

Tags: static-analysis, pmd, cpd

That's about PMD static analyzer's feature: Copy-Paste Detector.

Yes, I read http://pmd.sourceforge.net/cpd.html thoroughly.

But if I run CPD from ant-task, I can fine-tune its work by specifying `ignoreLiterals` and `ignoreIdentifiers`. How can I specify these keys using command-line?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it's currently not possible (with pmd 4.2.6 and pmd 4.1.1).

A simple `Properties` object contains the `ignoreLiterals` and `ignoreIdentifiers` settings, but the command line [`CPD.main()`](http://pmd.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pmd/tags/pmd/pmd_release_4_2_6/src/net/sourceforge/pmd/cpd/CPD.java?revision=7261&view=markup&sortby=file) method does not pass any Properties object to the `LanguageFactory` as the ant task ([`CPDTask`](http://pmd.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pmd/tags/pmd/pmd_release_4_2_6/src/net/sourceforge/pmd/cpd/CPDTask.java?revision=7261&view=markup&sortby=file)) does. Furthermore, if I'm correct, the `CPDTask` pass these properties to the [`LanguageFactory.createLanguage(String language, Properties properties)`](http://pmd.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/pmd/tags/pmd/pmd_release_4_2_6/src/net/sourceforge/pmd/cpd/LanguageFactory.java?revision=7261&view=markup&sortby=file) method, but this method does not use the properties argument. So, IMO the `ignoreLiterals` and `ignoreIdentifiers` settings are ignored by the ant task.

[Here is an old issue about this](http://sourceforge.net/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=2540597&group_id=56262&atid=479923), which is still open. The patch looks correct, maybe it still works. Unfortunately it does not contain any fixes for the command line `CPD` class. Perhaps it fixes the ant task. Anyway, if you really need this functionality it does not look too hard to fix these issues.

Answer (score 0):

According to the notes for PMD 4.3 at [sourceforge](http://sourceforge.net/projects/pmd/files/pmd/4.3/) this issue has been fixed.